# A particular field generated from a set

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

I am trying to understand a problem from my book regarding field extensions and fields generated from sets.

I have shown the set $B_0 = \lbrace (0,0),(1,0) \rbrace$ to generate a field $Q$ which consists of all elements of the form $(a,0)$, where $a \in \mathbb{Q}$. This field is then isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ with the map

$\sigma : Q \to \mathbb{Q} \quad $ , $\quad \sigma [(a,0)] = a.$

Suppose now we add an element $(1,\sqrt{3}) $ to $B_0$ such that we get $B_1 = \lbrace (0,0),(1,0),(1,\sqrt{3}) \rbrace $. What field would $B_1$ generate? My book claims that this field is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$, but i have trouble seeing this. In similar way to how we found $\sigma$ for $B_0$, what would an isomorphism look like for the field generated by $B_1$?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we call the field generated by $B_1$ something, say $F$, then the map \begin{align*}F &\to \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})\\(x,y\sqrt{3})&\mapsto x+y\sqrt{3} \end{align*}
is an isomorphism.

To prove that:

Firstly, it is well-defined, as $x$ and $y$ are rational for all elements of $F$, so $x+y\sqrt{3}$ is, indeed, in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$.

Secondly, it's clearly a field homomorphism (check everything if you're so inclined).

Thirdly, it's injective, since  if $x + y \sqrt{3} = 0$ with $x$ and $y$ rational, then $x = y = 0$.

Finally, it's surjective, since we can get all $x + y\sqrt{3}$ in this way, as the image of $(x,y\sqrt{3}) = y(1,\sqrt{3})+(x-y)(1,0)$.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again @user3482749, but I have been thinking about your answer and something still does not make sense to me. Is (x,y\sqrt{3}) really the form every number in F has? Is it not true that we also have elements (a,b) in F, where b is an integer? If so, I do not see how we can write this as (x,y\sqrt{3}). Thank you very much!

Comment: This is where we need slightly more detail: what, exactly, are your field operations? My answer is correct for the ones that I was thinking of, but it occurs to me that these aren't the only option, or even necessarily the most obvious ones.

Comment: Aha, that was exactly what I needed to hear. I proved the isomorphism you provided me with, and it makes sense to me now. Again, thank you very much!